# IOS 7.1 Xcode RSS feeds SearchBar do not display the search results.

Tags: ios, search, rss, feed

I am newbie an trying to develop a simple news reader application using rss feeds'. now i am stuck with the search bar. the problem is it loads all data in tableview but when I search from search bar it does not populate searchResults.

I am trying to filter search result from title
here is the code.

```
    #import "APPMasterViewController.h"

    #import "APPDetailViewController.h"

    @interface APPMasterViewController () {
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableArray *feeds;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSMutableString *title;
    NSMutableString *link;
    NSString *element;

    }
    @property (strong,nonatomic ) NSArray *searchResults;
    @end

    @implementation APPMasterViewController
    @synthesize mynewsFeed;

    - (void)awakeFromNib
   {
    [super awakeFromNib];
   }

   - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [ super viewDidLoad];

    feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:mynewsFeed];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];

    self.searchResults = [[NSArray alloc] init];
   }

      - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   #pragma mark - Table View

   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section
    {
    //  return feeds.count;
     if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    else
    {
        return feeds.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if( tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
    }
    else
    {

      cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
    }
    return cell;
}



-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([[self searchDisplayController] isActive])
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:cell ];
    }
}

#pragma for searching

-(void)FilterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",searchText];
    self.searchResults = [feeds filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"All my array list: %@", self.searchResults);
}


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self FilterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}

#pragma parser methods

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    element = elementName;

    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    }

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];

        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

    }

}

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

        if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
            [title appendString:string];
        } else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
            [link appendString:string];
        }

    }

    - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
    #pragma for Segue

    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
        if ([[self searchDisplayController] isActive])
        {

                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView] indexPathForCell:cell];
                feeds = [[self searchResults] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
            [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];

        }

        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
        {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];
        }
    }

    @end


NSLOG:::===
015-04-08 13:20:45.742 RSSreader[1117:914955] table content: (
        {
        link = "http://indiatoday.feedsportal.com/c/33614/f/589699/s/45338e70/sc/28/l/0Lindiatoday0Bintoday0Bin0Cstory0Capple0Eindia0Eearns0E0U10Ebillion0Ein0Erevenues0C10C4290A490Bhtml/story01.htm";
        title = "Apple India earns $1 billion in revenues";
    },
        {
        link = "http://indiatoday.feedsportal.com/c/33614/f/589699/s/45338e6d/sc/7/l/0Lindiatoday0Bintoday0Bin0Cstory0Cpadma0Evibhushan0Econferred0Eon0Eamitabh0Ebachchan0C10C4290A470Bhtml/story01.htm";
        title = "Big B receives Padma Vibhushan, Abhishek and Aishwarya attend ceremony";
    },
        {
        link = "http://indiatoday.feedsportal.com/c/33614/f/589699/s/45338e74/sc/15/l/0Lindiatoday0Bintoday0Bin0Cstory0C40A0A0A0Eusers0Eto0Etry0Eout0Ethe0Elg0Eg40Eprior0Eto0Ethe0Elaunch0C10C4290A40A0Bhtml/story01.htm";
        title = "4000 users to try out the LG G4 prior to the launch";
    };]
2015-04-08 13:20:49.026 RSSreader[1117:914955] All my array list: (
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed - [self.tableView reloadData]; in FilterContentForSearchText method

Comment: i Have tried with that yet no result still search result not updated . In my log the predicate dent fetch for the results and there is no content in the searchResults.

Comment: [[feeds filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy]; change with this. check what this is returning.

Comment: nope ,even with this it is not showing up the content after typing characters in search bar. i tried commenting the tableview.reload still no effect. :(

Comment: is it happening due to multiple values in the array feeds ?? i doubt!

Comment: change SELF to SELF.title

Comment: nope ! app terminated with this -
Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:6116
2015-04-08 15:56:45.907 RSSreader[1866:1348012] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: First make sure predicate working fine and you are getting results. Above issue seems dequeue method return nil so check this - UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

Comment: yes i am trying to make sure about the predicate but it does not filter accordingly. i am stuck where as to how to filter the feeds (multiple value array) using predicate ...:( it returns no results in NSLog !!! blank

Comment: I have tested predicate for multiple value array works fine. - NSArray* names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Joe",@"firstname",                    @"Bloggs",@"surname",nil],
                      [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       @"Simon",@"firstname",
                       @"Templar",@"surname",
                       nil],nil];
    NSArray *filtered = [names filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname contains[c] 'j'"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",filtered);